# SQLite FTS3 simulate LIKE somestring%

Tags: android, sqlite, fts3

I'm writing a dictionary app and need to do the usual word suggesting while typing.

`LIKE somestring%` is rather slow (~1300ms on a ~100k row table) so I've turned to FTS3.

Problem is, I haven't found a sane way to search from the beginning of a string.
Now I'm performing a query like

```
SELECT word, offsets(entries) FROM entries WHERE word MATCH '"chicken *"';
```

, then parse the offsets string in code.

Are there any better options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, make sure to set the index on field `word` and use

```
word >= 'chicken ' AND word < 'chicken z'
```

instead of LIKE or MATCH or GLOB