# How to display the word to starts with apple instead of displaying every apple found using FTS?

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search, android-sqlite

I am currently using the Sample from the SearchableDictionary which uses FTS, however when I enter the word "apple" it displays all apple words instead of only the word that starts with apple. I would like to know if there are anyway to display a list
eg)
1) Apple
2) Apple pie

instead of 
1) Adam's apple
2) Apple
3) Apple pie
4) Big apple

using android FTS.

According to what I understand from FTS is that it uses MATCH instead of LIKE and it functions like the LIKE %something% of the normal SQLite Query

I would appreciate it very much if someone can tell me how should I do it.

Thank you.

Comment: Both "Adam's apple" and "Big apple" have "apple" in them, and therefore would match `%LIKE%`.

Comment: is there anyway to change it so that it will only display words that start with Apple?.

Comment: or a method to make it similar to LIKE something% ? ty

Comment: "Big apple" consists of two words. What do you mean with "word"? The entire contents of a column?

Comment: Yes Big apple consist of 2 words but I would like to make it in such a way that it will only display the word that starts with "apple".eg) like the Oxford dictionary, when I enter the word "apple", it will display all words that start with apple - 1) Apple and 2) Apple pie instead of displaying Adam's apple and Big apple.Also, I noticed that when I enter a char "B", it will display all words that starts with "B" in the oxford dictionary, but in this searchable dicationary sample, it will display "Asomething followed by Bsomething (eg.A-bomb) instead of displaying the words that start with B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Query in your code:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Column_name MATCH 'apple*';
```

Check this link: http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3

The FTS engine provides that information via the offsets virtual function.
Try this

```
SELECT offsets(docs) FROM docs WHERE docs MATCH 'apple*';
```

Enter this in your code:

```
 Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT column_name, offsets(Tablename) FROM entries WHERE column_name MATCH '"apple *"'",null);
```

Then use cursor.

Comment: I had tried this method before and it give me Adam's apple, Big apple, apple pie and apple instead of only Apple and apple pie.

Comment: Chk this link same question asked by you .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432314/using-sqlite-with-fts-on-android.. I am still trying to find out .. till that time check this link please post the answer if it works

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734828/sqlite-fts3-simulate-like-somestring .. Check this link too

Comment: thank you very much for all the links and guidance, but may I know which code of line should I modify so that it will become "SELECT offsets(docs) FROM docs WHERE docs MATCH 'apple*';" ? I am not very sure which one i should change. Do I have to change this "Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
                               columns, selection, selectionArgs, null,  null, KEY_WORD );" to this Cursor cursor = mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("select * from FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE MATCH 'apple*' " , null);" ?

Comment: I had also tried changing this  String[] col = new String[] {
               BaseColumns._ID,
               DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
               DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION,
               SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID}; to this , String[] col = new String[] {
              BaseColumns._ID,
              "offset("+DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD+")",
              DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION,
              SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID}; but it seems like the application lost it function when i change it, May I know if I changed the wrong thing? ty

Comment: and I had also tried the last link that u gave me . I had tried replacing this Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
                col,selection, selectionArgs, null,  null, KEY_WORD ); with this for testing Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
                              col,"suggest_text_1 >= ? AND suggest_text_1 <'apple z' ", new String[]{"apple"}, null,  null, KEY_WORD ); and it still doesnt seem to work T.T. or is it that I wrote the codes wrongly ?

Comment: hi I tried the link that u gave me again just now and this one works for me String selection = KEY_WORD + " >='" + convertedQuery +"'"; =). Thank you very much Zohra Khan, u are my life saviour . *hugs* XD. I appreciate it very much for your help . Thank you !!! .

Comment: I had already posted the exact code below, hope that it can help others too . and ty again =).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did, inside the DictionaryDatabase.java file of the SearchableDictionary. I modified some of the method codes into these:

```
     public Cursor getWordMatches(String query, String[] columns)
     {
        String selection = KEY_WORD + " >='" + query +"'"; 
        return query(selection, columns);
     }


     private Cursor query(String selection, String[] columns)
     {

            SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
            builder.setTables(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
            builder.setProjectionMap(mColumnMap);

            Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
                   columns,selection,null, null,  null, KEY_WORD );

            if (cursor == null) {
                return null;
            } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                cursor.close();
                return null;
            }
            return cursor;
        }
```